# How can i pass the class object into the BroadCastReviever from the mainActivity class

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, android-notifications, android-broadcast

I am making an flash application an i want to have a On/Off button in the notification bar and on that button click i want to perform some action. What i am doing is this...

```
    Intent switchIntent = new Intent(this, switchOffButtonListener.class);

    PendingIntent pendingSwitchIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
            switchIntent, 0);

    remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.closeOnFlash,
            pendingSwitchIntent);
```

but i want to do this how can i do this

```
  //switchOffButtonListener notificationOnOff= new switchOffButtonListener(flash,soundFlashing,closeOnFlash);

    Intent switchIntent = new Intent(this, notificationOnOff);

    PendingIntent pendingSwitchIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
            switchIntent, 0);

    remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.closeOnFlash,
            pendingSwitchIntent);
```

i know intent only take class not the object but i want to pass the classes object into the onRecieve f BroadCast Reciever and want to use them there can anyone help me how i can do this, i read links but wasn't able to apply. Sorry if this is a silly question i am new to Android Programming so please help me out even it's foolish to ask.

Comment: make the class implements ``Parceble``, and put it into intent?

Comment: can you please explain in detail i will be thankful to you, or give me a link where i can find some help. Thanks a lot.

Comment: try the answer' s link below?

Answer (score 1):

Serialize object may help in your case. It will convert your object into String.
Just serialize your object and pass it.

Below link may help you. 
[How to send an object from one Android Activity to another using Intents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139134/how-to-send-an-object-from-one-android-activity-to-another-using-intents)

Comment: thanks for helping i did it using static variable in the parent class, but its quite useful to me so thanks a lot.